# Map source class to a target field

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm working on spring boot application where, I have two classes namely A and B.

```
@Data
class A{
 int id;
 String name;
}
```

```
@Data
class B{
 int bId;
 A a;
}
```

I need to map a field of class `B` which is `a` using `mapstruct`. How to map a source class `A` to target field `a` as well as to class `B`.
Example mapper will be like

```
@Mapping(source="id", target="bId")
B fromClassA(A a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@AfterMapping`, something like this:

```
@Mapping(source="id", target="bId")
B fromClassA(A a);
@AfterMapping
default void fillAinB(@MappingTarget B target, A source) {
  b.setA(source);
}
```

Comment: There is a better approach to this with only using `@Mapping`. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do the mapping would be to define it in `@Mapping`.

e.g.

```
@Mapping(source="id", target="bId")
@Mapping(target = "a", source="a")
B fromClassA(A a);
```

You can use the name of the parameter in the `Mapping#source`